# Using a directive's compile function with an isolate scope seems to access the wrong scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm not sure if this is an angularjs bug or if I am doing something wrong, but when i create a directive using an isolate scope as well as a compile function to programmatically modify the template, the wrong scope is used. What's interesting is that if I change the ng-repeat to `item in users`, which should not work as I am using an isolate scope...it actually works. Even more confusing...this code actually works correctly in angular 1.1.3. Anyone know whats going on?

Fiddles:

Not working in angular 1.2.3 - http://jsbin.com/iPIbubA/12/edit

Working in angular 1.1.3 as is - http://jsbin.com/iPIbubA/7/edit

Working in angular 1.2.3 with "item in users"  http://jsbin.com/iPIbubA/15/edit

For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Demo Blog</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div ng-app="app" class="container">
    <h1>Blog Demo</h1>
    <div class="row" ng-controller="main">
      <collection items="users">
        {{ $index + 1 }} - {{ item.name}} / {{ item.email }}
      </collection>
    </div>
  </div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.3/angular.min.js"></script>  
</body>
</html>


var app = angular.module('app', [ ]);

app.controller("main", function($scope) {

  $scope.users = [
    { name : "bob", email : "bob@aol.com" },
    { name : "joe", email : "joe@aol.com" }
  ];

});

app.directive("collection", function() {

  return {
    restrict : "E",

    scope : {
      "items" : "="
    },

    compile : function(el, attrs) {
      var itemTemplate = el.text();
      // if I change ng-repeat to "item in users" it works!
      el.html('<ul><li ng-repeat="item in items">' + itemTemplate + '</li></ul>');
    }

  };

});
```

Comment: This is a bug in AngularJS 1.1. Relevant issue on GitHub, https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4889.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `transclude`:

```
app.directive("collection", function() {
    return {
        restrict : "E",
        scope : {
            "items" : "="
        },
        template : '<ul><li ng-repeat="item in items">
        <span ng-transclude></span></li></ul>',
        transclude : true
    };
});
```

Comment: Cool! So transcluding that content doesn't use the parent scope in which items is undefined? I thought that was the whole point of transclusion?

Comment: The transcluded content does have access to the outside scope: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: but it also has access to the isolate scope as well in this example? as items is only defined here?

Comment: Yeah. `$index` and `item` are available only inside the directive's scope. So transclusion uses that scope.

Comment: This looks to be the commit that changed this behavior: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/d0efd5eefcc0aaf167c766513e152b74dd31bafe